# launchFragmentinHiltContainer throws Method addObserver must be called on the main thread

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

I am trying to perform integration testing and use `launchFragmentInHiltContainer` to start my fragment for specific scenario. However I receive and error
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method addObserver must be called on the main thread` on the `navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)` line. Below I have provided my test class and the launchFragmentInHiltContainer.

```
@HiltAndroidTest
class SensorsTests {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @Inject
    lateinit var repository: MockRepositoryImpl

    @BeforeAll
    fun beforeAll() {
        hiltRule.inject()
    }

    @Test
    fun userSensorsAreVisible() {
        val navController = TestNavHostController(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
        navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)

        launchFragmentInHiltContainer<SensorsFragment>(navHostController = navController)

        Thread.sleep(10000)
    }

}
```

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
    fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
    @StyleRes themeResId: Int = R.style.Theme_SensorsTracker,
    navHostController: NavHostController? = null,
    crossinline action: Fragment.() -> Unit = {}
) {
    val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
        ComponentName(
            ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
            HiltTestActivity::class.java
        )
    ).putExtra(
        "androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY",
        themeResId
    )

    ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
        val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
            Preconditions.checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
            T::class.java.name
        )

        fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs

        fragment.viewLifecycleOwnerLiveData.observeForever { viewLifecycleOwner ->
            if (viewLifecycleOwner != null) {
                navHostController?.let {
                    Navigation.setViewNavController(fragment.requireView(), it)
                }
            }
        }

        activity.supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
            .commitNow()

        fragment.action()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. My extension function looks like this:

```
  inline fun <reified T : Fragment> launchFragmentInHiltContainer(
        fragmentArgs: Bundle? = null,
        @StyleRes themeResId: Int = androidx.fragment.testing.R.style.FragmentScenarioEmptyFragmentActivityTheme,
        fragmentFactory: FragmentFactory? = null,
        crossinline action: T.() -> Unit = {}
    ) {
        val startActivityIntent = Intent.makeMainActivity(
            ComponentName(
                ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),
                HiltTestActivity::class.java
            )
        ).putExtra(
            "androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario.EmptyFragmentActivity.THEME_EXTRAS_BUNDLE_KEY",
            themeResId
        )
    
        ActivityScenario.launch<HiltTestActivity>(startActivityIntent).onActivity { activity ->
            fragmentFactory?.let {
                activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = it
            }
            val fragment: Fragment = activity.supportFragmentManager.fragmentFactory.instantiate(
                Preconditions.checkNotNull(T::class.java.classLoader),
                T::class.java.name
            )
    
            fragment.arguments = fragmentArgs
            activity.supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "")
                .commitNow()
    
            (fragment as T).action()
        }
    }
```

And then in my tests I was calling:

```
launchFragmentInHiltContainer<PokemonsFragment>(null, R.style.AppTheme) {
            navController.setGraph(R.navigation.navigation)
            navController.setCurrentDestination(R.id.pokemonsFragment)
            Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
```

}

Try to adjust it accordingly and let me know if it works. I can even post you the repository if you want

Comment: Hi, I could not launch your provided code as well because of the same error. I found that I had to call `runOnUiThread` and use `navController.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)` while on UI thread. Not sure why as in the original documentation this step was not indicated. My solution helped to at least run the code, but I believe it's more of the workaround, instead of the viable solution.

Comment: Another guess would be that you are adding the observer on a background thread somewhere instead on the main thread? Can this be the case? Can you post your Fragment?